# .Net Maui - Operation Timeout when trying to build

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

I'm having an issue when building/running a default new Maui application.

I create a new `.NET Maui App (Preview)` and make no changes to the autogenerated codebase, but when I try to build or run the application I am getting the following timeout error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MAUI0000    System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenAndPush(Uri uri)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.PushExternalEntityOrSubset(String publicId, String systemId, Uri baseUri, String entityName)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy_PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseExternalSubset()
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseInDocumentDtd(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.Parse(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.System.Xml.IDtdParser.ParseInternalDtd(IDtdParserAdapter adapter, Boolean saveInternalSubset)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDtd()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at Svg2VectorDrawable.SvgTree.Parse(String filename) in /Users/runner/work/Svg2VectorDrawable.Net/Svg2VectorDrawable.Net/Svg2VectorDrawable.Net/SvgTree.cs:line 35
   at Svg2VectorDrawable.Svg2Vector.Parse(String file) in /Users/runner/work/Svg2VectorDrawable.Net/Svg2VectorDrawable.Net/Svg2VectorDrawable.Net/Svg2Vector.cs:line 84
   at Svg2VectorDrawable.Svg2Vector.ParseSvgToXml(String inputSvgFilename, Stream outputStream) in /Users/runner/work/Svg2VectorDrawable.Net/Svg2VectorDrawable.Net/Svg2VectorDrawable.Net/Svg2Vector.cs:line 773
   at Svg2VectorDrawable.Svg2Vector.Convert(String inputSvgFilename, String outputXmlFilename) in /Users/runner/work/Svg2VectorDrawable.Net/Svg2VectorDrawable.Net/Svg2VectorDrawable.Net/Svg2Vector.cs:line 759
   at Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.AndroidAdaptiveIconGenerator.Generate() in D:\a\1\s\src\SingleProject\Resizetizer\src\AndroidAdaptiveIconGenerator.cs:line 73
   at Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.ResizetizeImages.ProcessAppIcon(ResizeImageInfo img, ConcurrentBag`1 resizedImages) in D:\a\1\s\src\SingleProject\Resizetizer\src\ResizetizeImages.cs:line 132
   at Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.ResizetizeImages.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0(ResizeImageInfo img) in D:\a\1\s\src\SingleProject\Resizetizer\src\ResizetizeImages.cs:line 88
   at Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.AsyncTaskExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<ParallelForEach>b__0(TSource s) in D:\a\1\s\src\SingleProject\Resizetizer\src\AsyncTaskExtensions.cs:line 21   MauiApp C:\Users\rea\.nuget\packages\microsoft.maui.resizetizer.sdk\6.0.101-preview.10.2068\build\Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk.targets    463
```

I am running

- `vs2022 preview 1.1`
- `dotnet v6.0.100`
- `Android 12.0 (SDK 31)`

Can someone help with what I'm missing?

Comment: Interesting! Do you have this project somewhere on GitHub? Or would you be able to put it somewhere?

Comment: Sure, I just pushed it out to a GitHub repo now: https://github.com/robearlam/MauiTest

It's a strange one though, its just the default file new project, assets no changes. I also ran the Maui-check tool and it all came back green, so I'm a but stumped!

Comment: I would use VS Installer to "Repair" VS 2022 Preview. That fixed an (unrelated) issue I had.

Comment: I've done a complete uninstall and reinstall of VS and still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took a while! It's weird that it would spawn this error, but I think you might want to avoid using `MauiApp` as a name for your solution and project as it's also a type in the source and that causes issues for me to build it as well.

Try again with a solution with a different name and let me know if that solves it!

Comment: Good point, I've regenerated the project using a different name that doens't clash however I'm still getting the same timeout error?

Pushed the changes to the same repo: https://github.com/robearlam/MauiTest

Comment: Do you have some kind of firewall or any other network thing that might be in the way? All works fine here :)

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking it might be something getting blocked by our Corp firewall settings, as it works fine on my personal machine.

Is there are list of what external services it needs to access that we need to whitelist?

Comment: Not that I know of, I've never heard of this before tbh :D