# Setting MauiSplashScreen tag on MyMauiProject.csproj with a mp4 file throw null exception from Resizetizer/SkiaSharpBitmapTools, looks hardcoded trash

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, nullreferenceexception, csproj, maui

Setting the *MauiSplashScreen* tag inside my **net6.0** *MyMauiProject.csproj* pointing to a mp4 file makes it throw a **null** exception from Resizetizer/SkiaSharpBitmapTools. It looks like hardcoded trash from Microsoft. I don't even have a 'D:' drive on my machine, just 'C:', but the error points to `D:\a\1\s\src\SingleProject\Resizetizer\src\SkiaSharpBitmapTools.cs:line 29` , a project I never created.

Was searching like a crazy on google, but there is nothing about it.
Even after it changes back to a gif and also changes to a svg, the error stays there.
Thinking about recreating the project and copying my source code to see if it fixes it, but I cant do it every time and that isn't a good solution.
I'm on a tight deadline project. I can't do in on Xamarin Forms because MS is discontinuing it and looks I can't do on MAUI too.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MAUI0000    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.SkiaSharpBitmapTools.GetOriginalSize() in D:\a\1\s\src\SingleProject\Resizetizer\src\SkiaSharpBitmapTools.cs:line 29
   at Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.SkiaSharpTools.Resize(DpiPath dpi, String destination) in D:\a\1\s\src\SingleProject\Resizetizer\src\SkiaSharpTools.cs:line 47
   at Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Resizer.Resize(DpiPath dpi, String inputsFile) in D:\a\1\s\src\SingleProject\Resizetizer\src\Resizer.cs:line 101
   at Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.ResizetizeImages.ProcessImageResize(ResizeImageInfo img, DpiPath[] dpis, ConcurrentBag`1 resizedImages) in D:\a\1\s\src\SingleProject\Resizetizer\src\ResizetizeImages.cs:line 172
   at Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.ResizetizeImages.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0(ResizeImageInfo img) in D:\a\1\s\src\SingleProject\Resizetizer\src\ResizetizeImages.cs:line 88
   at Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.AsyncTaskExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<ParallelForEach>b__0(TSource s) in D:\a\1\s\src\SingleProject\Resizetizer\src\AsyncTaskExtensions.cs:line 21   MyMauiProject   C:\Users\MySelf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.maui.resizetizer.sdk\6.0.101-preview.11.2349\build\Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk.targets 463
```

When clicking on the error, the IDE points to:

```
<!-- Resize the images -->
<ResizetizeImages
    PlatformType="$(ResizetizerPlatformType)"
    IntermediateOutputPath="$(_MauiIntermediateImages)"
    InputsFile="$(_ResizetizerInputsFile)"
    Images="@(MauiImage->Distinct())">
</ResizetizeImages>
```

I never ever touched on this block.
Closing and opening Visual Studio/Project doesnt fix it either.
It looks like it's pointing to [here](https://github.com/Redth/ResizetizerNT/blob/319fc3f085021dea4e836c0072adc754b0436d66/Resizetizer.NT/SkiaSharpBitmapTools.cs#L29).

Comment: *cant do in on Xamarin Forms because MS is discontinuing it*". If you are on a tight deadline, you absolutely *should* do it in Xamarin Forms, not Maui. Yes, this means a year from now you'll need to make some changes to go to Maui - but its too soon to rely on Maui for an app that needs to be released on a deadline. The Maui team is doing everything they can to minimize needed changes (yet some changes will be required, to fix limitations of Xamarin Forms).

Comment: The ability to animate depends on the target platform. See [Animated GIF Splash Screen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41ea7fe5-d7ff-47c2-ae5d-588bb34ea81e/animated-gif-splash-screen-using-ffimageloading?forum=xamarinforms) for one discussion. On Android, it should be possible, based on what people say. On iOS, I believe you have to use a still image (the first frame of your animation) as splash screen, then as early in code as possible, start playing the animation.

Comment: To add to what @ToolmakerSteve is saying: Xamarin.Forms will be supported up to *2 years* after .NET MAUI is released. That means it will be here at least until Q2 2024 at this point. If you want to get started today Xamarin.Forms is the right way, .NET MAUI is in preview and things are likely to change or unstable.

Comment: In regard to your error, don't focus on the path in there, that is just the path that it's compiled on in the build pipeline and it points to that as the source of this error. Instead focus on what you're trying to do and what doesn't seem to work. In this state it's hard to say something useful about the issue you seem to encounter.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue.  The problem was that I had a non-image file (ie a file called list.txt) in the Resources/Images folder.

Removing the file fixed the issue and the code ran correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Another person had a related error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358498/net-maui-operation-timeout-when-trying-to-build), the solution was reinstall all environment.
I Think you realized the error isnt with your code but with: `C:\Users\MySelf\.nuget\packages\microsoft.maui.resizetizer.sdk\6.0.101-preview.11.2349`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The linked error is different than the situation in this question, imho.